# How Can I Resolve a "Couldn't Find a Component Error"?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

Currently, I am having a problem that when I am trying to render Ionicons using Fonts.loadAsync, it works, but it gave me an error, and I fixed it, but then another error popped up, one that I can understand, but can solve in this situation, because it seemed like nonsense since I did everything correct. The error is: "Couldn't Find A Component, getComponent, or children for the Screen -------" (hiding screen name). I already have everything in the correct position and correct place, but it didn't do anything.

Here is my Navigator Code for App.js:

```
// import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import * as Font from "expo-font"
import { StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Platform, 
  View, 
  SafeAreaView, 
  Button, 
  Alert,
  Dimensions} from 'react-native';
import {useDeviceOrientation, useDimensions} from '@react-native-community/hooks'
import React, {useCallback} from "react";
import WelcomeScreen from './app/assets/screens/WelcomeScreen';
import SigningInFirst from "./app/assets/screens/SigningInFirst";
import SettingsScreen from "./app/assets/screens/SettingsScreen";
import {useNavigation, NavigationContainer} from "@react-navigation/native"
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import SecondLoginScreen from './app/assets/screens/SecondLoginScreen';
import ThirdSignStep from './app/assets/screens/ThirdSignStep';
import LoginScreen from './app/assets/screens/LoginScreen';
import MapScreen from './app/assets/screens/MapScreen';
import BottomTabNavigation from './app/assets/screens/BottomTabNavigation';
import MessagingScreen from './app/assets/screens/MessagingScreen'
import Profile from './app/assets/screens/Profile'
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
export default function App() {
// const orient  = useDeviceOrientation();
// const handlePress = () => console.log("ArrivTrack")
// const navigation = useNavigation();


  return (
    // <WelcomeScreen />
    // <SignInJs />
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name = "WelcomeScreen" component={WelcomeScreen} options={{headerShown:false}} />
        <Stack.Screen name = "Message" component={MessagingScreen} options={{headerShown:false}} />
        <Stack.Screen name = "Profile" component={Profile} options={{headerShown:false}} />
        <Stack.Screen name = "Step1" component={SignInJs} options={{headerShown:false}} />
        <Stack.Screen name = "Step2" component={SecondLoginScreen} options={{headerShown:false}} />
        <Stack.Screen name = "Step3" component={ThirdSignStep} options={{headerShown:false}} />
        <Stack.Screen name = "LoginPage" component={LoginScreen} options={{headerShown:false}} />
        <Stack.Screen name = "MapScreen" component={MapScreen} options={{headerShown:false}} />
        <Stack.Screen name = "SettingsScreen" component={SettingsScreen} options={{headerShown:false}} />
        <Stack.Screen name = "BottomTabNavigation" component={BottomTabNavigation} options={{headerShown:false}}/>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
    
  );
}

const stylesContainer = {backgroundColor:"black"}
const textStyles = {color:"white"}
const buttonStyles = {color:"white", backgroundColor:"dodgerblue"}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    paddingTop: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 20: 0,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    // color: "white",
  },
});
```

And my code for the Fonts.loadAsync:

```
import * as Font from "expo-font";
export async function loadFontsAsync(){
    await Font.loadAsync({
        ionicons:require("./Ionicons.ttf")
        
    })
}
```

And the code for the page where the weird error is being caused:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Ionicons } from 'react-native';
import { loadFontsAsync } from './loadFonts';

const Profile = () => {
  const [fontsLoaded, setFontsLoaded] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const loadFonts = async () => {
      await loadFontsAsync();
      setFontsLoaded(true);
    };

    loadFonts();
  }, []);

  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return <Text>Loading fonts...</Text>; // Or render a loading indicator
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <Ionicons fontFamily="ionicons" name="person" color="red" size={36} />
      {/* Other components */}
    </View>
  );
};

export default Profile;
```

And the error image:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkFVN.png)

- I tried to solve this by myself first, since I knew how to fix it.
- Tried Using a bit of AI help.

I expected that the error would go away if I corrected syntax, and I would see my image. But it actually turned out to be false and the error that I don't know why is there is hanging around.

Comment: Did you export `BottomTabNavigation` correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to import SignInJs in App.js.

Comment: I forgot, but I actually changed the name for the import SigningInFirst on purpose, but I also forgot to change the one for the import as well. In my actual code, SignInJs is actually imported. Thanks for trying though!